# this is what type of join or this is what type of queries i not understand

Tags: mysql, sql

SELECT b.*, a.cust_name
FROM orders b, customer a
WHERE a.customer_id=b.customer_id
AND b.ord_date='2012-08-17';

Comment: it is the same as `SELECT b.*, a.cust_name FROM orders b join  customer a on a.customer_id=b.customer_id where b.ord_date='2012-08-17';`

Comment: Please don't use as many tags as you can. We call it tag spamming. There's no obvious relationship to most of the tags you had and you have to decide which DB vendor you're targeting. I assumed MySql.

Comment: This is a comma join and out of favour , explicit joins being preferred. With the where clause is equivalent to an inner join (inner is optional and default) without the where clause would be equivalent to a cross join producing a cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

The "comma-separated list of tables" in the `FROM` clause was a syntax that was defined in the SQL-89 standard (from 1989 of course).

Three years later, in 1992 it was superseded by the JOIN clause in SQL-92 Standard. Don't use the old syntax from the 80s; it's obscure and difficult to debug.